# In angular can you groupby substring in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a div that I need to repeat by a sub group of newRat.  Can I create that sub group by grouping by substring?

This works, but I want newRat to be broken out more.

```
<div ng-repeat="(group, persons) in filteredPersons | groupBy:'newRat'">
```

Like this...

```
<div ng-repeat="(group, persons) in filteredPersons | groupBy:'newRat.substring(0,1)">
```

Each substring's first value is different, but the same for the groups.
Example data...
Group 1 = 9P, 9O, 9J
Group 2 = 7P, 7Y, 7J etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this component of angular is not that customisable. One approach would be to write your own filter. The other one is to add another key/value pair to your `filteredPersons` object, that equals `newRat.substring(0,1)` and do a `groupBy` on that.